# How do you define such map $(C^B \times B^A) \to C^A$?

Tags: proof-verification, category-theory, fake-proofs

Suppose that $\mathbf{C}$ be cartesian closed and $B$ is an object of it. We define two functors $\mathbf{C} \times \mathbf{C} \to \mathbf{C}$ by
$$ C^B \times B^A     \qquad\text{and}\qquad     C^A$$Now I want to show that there is a natural transformation between them, i.e. with components given by $$\eta_{(A,C)} : (C^B \times B^A) \to C^A $$but how can I define such mapping?
I'm a bit confused here.

Can't I just directly define $\eta_{(A,C)} (C^B \times B^A) := C^A$ and show that it is natural? Is it this trivial or I would be cheating in my definition?

Otherwise, how do you define such map? I tried manipulating evaluation and transposes, but I couldn't get anywhere.

Thanks!

Comment: There's only one reasonable candidate: composition. And yes, you have to use evaluation and transposition.

Comment: @ZhenLin Can you give me some hint? I am probably missing the obvious...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adjointness, morphisms 
$$C^B \times B^A \to C^A$$
are the same as morphisms
$$C^B \times B^A \times A \to C$$
of which there is a canonical one, namely, the following composite:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
C^B \times B^A \times A @>{\mathrm{id}_{C^B} \times \mathrm{ev}}>>
C^B \times B @>{\mathrm{ev}}>>
C
\end{CD}$$
I leave it to you to verify naturality.

Comment: +1 Thanks a bunch! The adjointness step is what I was missing!

Comment: By the way, does adjointness mean that those morphisms are really *equal*? Isn't it just that there is a bijection $\phi : Hom((C^B \times B^A) \times A, C) \cong Hom(C^B \times B^A, C^A)$? So my component should be $\phi (\mathrm{ev} (id_{C^B} \times \mathrm{ev}))$ right?

Comment: Of course they are not literally equal. They don't even have the same domain and codomain.